# Python: Sort text file twice and split to different files?

Tags: python, sorting, split

How do I sort first by line length, then alphabetically, then split by line length into seperate files?
I have a word list file like so:

```
a

actors

an

b

batter

but
```

I require one file (1.txt, 2.txt) for each line length, each sorted alphabetically. How might this be done?

The resulting file should look like:

1.txt

```
a
b
...
```

2.txt

```
an
by
...
```

etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "one file for each line length" What exactly should 1.txt and 2.txt contain?

Comment: n.txt should contain every line of input.txt that is n characters long, sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

OUTF = "{0}.txt".format

def sortWords(wordList):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in wordList:
        d[len(word)].append(word)
    return d

def readWords(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return [word for word in (line.strip() for line in inf.readlines()) if word]

def writeWords(fname, wordList):
    wordList.sort()
    with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
        outf.write('\n'.join(wordList))

def main():
    for wordLen,wordList in sortWords(readWords('words.txt')).iteritems():
        writeWords(OUTF(wordLen), wordList)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function into sort. Something like `lambda a, b: (len(a) < len(b)) if (len(a) != len(b)) else (a < b)` ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

to add to the previous answer:

```
files = {}
for word in sort(words, lambda a,b: (len(a) < len(b)) if (len(a) != len(b)) else (a < b)):
    if len(word) not in files:    
         files[len(word)] = open("{0}.txt".format(len(word)), "w")
    files[len(word)].write("{0}\n".format(word))
```

Comment: N.B. 'the previous answer' may change over time, since most users view answers sorted by vote count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
text = [x.strip() for x in """a

actors

an

b

batter

but""".splitlines() if x.strip()]

files = {}
for word in text:
    n = len(word)
    if n not in files:
        files[n] = open("%d.txt" % n, 'wt')
    files[n].write(word + "\n")

for file in files.itervalues():
    file.close()
```